# Accessing Distinct values of List within List for ListView

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a List "RootObject" that contains another list "Components". So basically each RootObject could have many Components. I need to get all Distinct values out of "Components" to bind to a ListView.

```
public class RootObject
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<string> Components { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I think I may need to use SelectMany but not sure how to get them...
For example I have my root object into

`mylist = deserial.Deserialize<List<RootObject>>(response);`

This works.  I then need to get a list of Components into a ListView

```
`ListView.DataSource = //get list of Components`
```

Comment: do you want to retrieve all the components of each RootObject into one collection?

Comment: I edited my question to explain a little more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets the distinct components into a list:

```
var distinctComponents = rootObjects
    .SelectMany(r => r.Components)
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(c => c)
    .ToList();
```

I don't know which GUI technology you  are using, but a winforms [`ListView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview(v=vs.110).aspx) has no simple binding mechanism. You need to add items and subitems manually. So, you could also drop the `ToList()` and enumerate the query directly in a foreach-statement.

Answer (score 0):

for distinct components, you'll need something like this:

```
List<RootObject> values = new List<RootObject>(); // assuming this is the collection 
var distinctComponents = values.SelectMany(r => r.Components).Distinct().ToList();
```